# How many natural solutions does the equation $x^2 - c y^2 = 1$ have?

Tags: diophantine-equations

How many natural solutions has equation  $x^2-cy^2=1$ depends on value of $c$ . I think I've seen this problem somewhere as a theorem but I can't remember where .

Comment: May be here? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation

Comment: @gammatester , yes it is . Write it as answer and I shall accept it .Thank you!

Comment: This equation is also Project Euler's introduction to diophantine equations in [problem 66] (https://projecteuler.net/problem=66) or, as I like to call it, the Project Euler hazing ritual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Pell's equation, here is the entry at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation). Among others there you can find the result from Lagrange, that *as long as c is not a perfect square, Pell's equation has infinitely many distinct integer solutions,* and
how to find all solutions once you have a fundamental solution.

Comment: Perhaps quoting some content from the wikipedia article on why the contextual equations has these solutions etc. rather than just giving a link.

Answer (score 2):

The equation $X^2 - d Y^2 = 1$ for $d$ a positive integer, is called Pell equation (while Pell actually had not much to do with it); having this name at hand it will be easy to find lots of information on it. It indeed has infinitely many integral solutions.

One reason this equation is relevant is that it solutions are linked to invertible elements in the ring of algebraic integers of real quadratic fields.

Comment: I should also have said "except if $d$ is a perfect square" when saying the equation has infinitely many solutions. Good the other answer got expanded.